# ASP.NET CORE MVC - Redirecting same action to another controller in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my View I have standard Edit action next to each row in View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Person>
...
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.NameID">Edit</a> //
```

When clicked it goes to:

https://localhost:44312/Person/Edit/1
in case you are editing 1st row in View. 
That's standard behavior.

My question is how can I redirect that same action for same IDs to another controller? For example to:

https://localhost:44312/**People**/Edit/1

Comment: how about [``ActionLink``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

Comment: See [AnchorTagHelper Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `asp-controller="controllerName"`

In your case:

```
<a asp-controller="People" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.NameID">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Great. Works perfectly.